# How to know that App is not used from last 10 seconds in ionic 3/4?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I am Working with ionic 3/4 app, what I want to do is to navigate user to dashboard if app is not used since last 10 seconds
. But have no idea how to get 10 seconds to fire navigation process. Do anyone have idea or plugin suggestion for this one ?

Comment: If the app is not in use like it has no interaction in the screen or if the app was minimized for 10 seconds

Comment: @GabrielBarreto exactly I want that you said , just want to get time duration(10 seconds) in variable .